# Methods for sending dynamic content in Django apps

Tags: django, dynamic-data

I'm quite new to all of this, so I apologize if the language I'm using isn't indicative of what I'm describing.

I am developing a Django app which my company will use to monitor bids at auctions which it sends out to various banks. I am at the stage now where the clients see the auction and its contents on one page, and we see pretty much the same thing on a different page. What I *want* to happen is for the clients to fill in their bids on all the things they want, hit "submit", whereupon on our (the admin) page, a new column pops into existence with the name of the bank and their bids on each item.

I don't think I can do this in jQuery. Do I have to use AJAX? PHP? Are all of these valid methods? I really don't know. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I use PHP and Django. But the easiest way to build like that is with Django+Ajax.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I installed Dajaxice and am trying to get to grips with that, but I am confused: you say you use PHP and Django, but it would be easier to use Django and Ajax. To use Ajax don't you have to incorporate PHP/ASP anyway? All of this server-side stuff is confusing the hell out of me >_<

Comment: Yeah I use many programming languages but you just mention PHP and Django. Each of them provide a good output. I select Django than PHP because it is really easy to build application with django. For example in your case, clients must fill information when hit submit. You can finish it in less than hour or minutes.

Comment: Ajax is just a script that will help you in submitting form without loading the page. With that client will like it because it is fast and easy.